# Is it possible to test High Availability with Google Cloud Memorystore

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-memorystore

I would like to trigger a failover situation by killing the master node, in order to validate that my app behaves correctly.

My application is a GKE backend.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to kill the Master node unless you delete the whole cluster. Since the Master node is a managed service within GKE, users do not have access to it.

If you would like access to the Master node, the only workaround I can provide at this time is to [create a custom cluster from scratch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/) using Google Compute Engine.